# How to change the position of the button through coding xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to align a button that I created through code, but I can't seem to change its position, my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.lineWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
        self.lineColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
        UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(20,100, 50, 50);
        //[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(3,20, 50, 50)];
        btn.center = self.center;

        [btn setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget: self 
                   action: @selector(clearButtonPressed:) 
         forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I remove the "btn.center =self.center" and try to set the X and Y position as

```
    "btn.frame =CGRectMake(3,20,50,50)"
```

it doesn't even display the button.
Please any help will be appreciated , thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [btn setCenter:center]; where center is a CGPoint?

Comment: did you mean like this :
[btn setCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
         btn.center = self.center;
if i remove the "btn.center = self.center" then the button doesnt display at all

Comment: I think I know what the problem might be, setting the centre in that method might actually be setting it within the context of that view. The solution might be to set the centre of the button in the same place that you call this method rather than inside that method.